# Creating a Webapp widget that pulls data from underlying polygons

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, widget, workforce

I am currently wondering what would be involved in creating a custom widget that does the following.

Widget would be based off a point feature class. When you create a new point the information from the underlying polygon (specific fields chosen) will be appended to a field in the point feature dataset. e.g. If I have parcel fabric (polygon) displayed and i draw a point on a property the newly created point would inherit the address (attribute info) from parcel fabric (polygon).

An excellent example of what I am trying to accomplish can be viewed in the [workforce](http://www.esri.com/products/workforce) for ArcGIS environment.

If you modify the assignments map that the application works off of and add a dataset (e.g. parcels or census, etc.) when you create a new assignment (point feature class) the pick point will append the popup info data from the polygon to the description field of the assignment dataset (point feature class).

Alternatively the [geo-form app](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=931653256fd24301a84fc77955914a82) would be ideal, the only difference is when you select your location it would pull the polygon data into your point feature attributes as well as let you fill in your own fields as well.

I realize that what I am doing may not be possible. I figured this would be the best place to get the conversation started.

Comment: Out of interest, is this hosted feature services or data from an Enterprise GDB.  If latter, if its native SQL geometry, you can have this run as a trigger at the DBMS end.